# Removing wordpress theme from particular pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom Wordpress theme that includes a header, footer, and a few other elements. It's great, but there are a few pages that I want to style completely differently. One of them is, for example, a landing page, where having the typical header makes no sense. How can I tell Wordpress not to use any themes on this page? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)**

For example, if you would like to use custom header or footer for your landing page you can do following in a separate .php file and declare it as a Page Template.

I'm assuming your header and footer file name `header-landing.php` and `footer-landing.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Landing Page
 */

get_header( 'landing' ); ?>

  // Landing Body

<?php get_footer( 'landing' ); ?>
```

If you wish no header or footer then, you can just omit `get_header()` or `get_footer()` function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditionals](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to decide when to load certain stylesheets onto certain pages.

For example, in your functions.php, you can use [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) to load in different stylesheets. In your php, you would say something like this:

```
function custom_page_style_sheet() {
   if (is_page() ):
   wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-page-styling', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-page.css' );
}}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_page_style_sheet');
```

Try this tutorial, which is where I grabbed the example code from:
http://wpsites.net/wordpress-themes/second-style-sheet-theme/